# excel type mismatch error on time identification sub

Tags: vba, excel, time, error-handling

I have a sub that should identify the hour and add one to the value of a cell in a corresponding row that has that hour in the second column. so for example if its 7:30 and i hit the button, it adds 1 to the cell in the row with 7:00. my code is giving me a type mismatch error when yesterday it worked perfectly. my code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Front End").Unprotect ("29745")
h = Hour(Now)
    For Each c In range("B8:B20")
        If h = Hour(c) Then
            c.Offset(0, 3) = c.Offset(0, 3) + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
Sheets("Front End").Protect ("29745")
Unload Me
End Sub
```

i cant for the life of me figure out what is wrong with the code, it worked all day yesterday when i wrote it.

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you paste up the contents of B8:B20?

Comment: Are you accounting for 24 hour time?

Comment: the values for time are on a 12 hour time scale. and the values in the B column are are the time its matching to

Comment: Where is the error exactly happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that the error is being caused by the fact that `Hour()` in Vba returns values from 0-23 representing a 24 hour timescale.  Since you have said that you are using a 12 hour timescale, you should use the `Mod` command with your time to add to the corresponding hour.

Further, if the value in `c.Offset(0,3)` is not numeric, you will get a type mismatch error with the `+ 1` command.  The easiest way to circumvent that issue would be to change that line to say `c.Offset(0,3) = CInt(c.Offset(0,3)) + 1` which will first convert the value in the cell to an integer to ensure no type mismatch errors are thrown

Comment: where would i add the Mod command exactly? The times its matching to are a in AM and PM format

Comment: @Vbasic4now if the times are in AM and PM format then there is no need for Mod (The hour function will read the PM format and add 12 accordingly).  I was assuming you hadn't included that formatting

Comment: @Vbasic4now  -[Mod function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634767.aspx) and [Hour function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264741.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If there is text in the target cell `c.Offset(0, 3)` it will cause a "type mismatch" error when it tries to increment the value. Check that the cell you are trying to update doesn't contain any text, even spaces.